# Missing operand after '12' operator error on finding the range between 2 dates

Tags: c#, ado.net

I'm getting the error "Missing operand after '12' operator" on executing the below code.

```
employee.Select(Table.Key + " = '" + dept.Key.ToString() + "' AND " +  Table.EnteredDate + "BETWEEN" + startDate + "AND" + endDate)))
```

Comment: You really need to provide some context here.

Comment: Before executing this line, in QuickWatch window look what is the final string that executes in Select.

Comment: How about you print out the string inside of `Select` and then maybe it will be easier to see what the problem is.

Comment: Also, what is the data type of `employee`? I bet it's a `DataTable`.

Comment: yes, you are correct. Employee is a table. I need to select rows based on r emploeetable key = empkey and entereddate between open and close date .

Comment: It's not a "table". It's a [`System.Data.DataTable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.aspx), right?

Comment: Yes it's a datatable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below code worked!

```
employee.Select(Table.Key + " = '" + dept.Key.ToString() + "' AND " + Table.EnteredDate + " >= '" + startDate.ToString("yyyyMMdd") + "' AND " + Table.EnteredDate + " <= '" + endDate.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
employee.Select(Table.Key + " = '" + dept.Key.ToString() + "' AND '" +  Table.EnteredDate.ToString("yyyyMMdd") + "' BETWEEN '" + startDate.ToString("yyyyMMdd") + "' AND '" + endDate.ToString("yyyyMMdd") + "'")))
```

Hope it works. Your input is insufficient.